# SpriteKit App glitching on iPhone 4 only

Tags: ios, app-store, sprite-kit, image-scaling, iphone-4

So i have recently released an app to the app store and it was working perfectly fine on all devices including the iPhone 4. Then i released an update which changed images completely and also made them better quality. The update was accepted by apple and all was good. I then updated on my iPhone 5 and the update looked fine. I also updated on an iPhone 4s and all looked good. However when i got it on to iPhone 4 two of the images were blacked out.

This is the code that adds one of the images  that is blacked out on the iPhone 4:

```
    SKSpriteNode* title = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"TITLE.png"];

    title.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2.1, self.frame.size.height * 15/20);
    title.size = CGSizeMake(title.frame.size.width/10.5, title.frame.size.height/10.5);
    [self addChild:title];
```

THIS IS IPHONE 4
[image: IPHONE 4]

THIS IS IPHONE 5...Dont worry about the ads
[image: IPHONE 5]

Comment: Does this happen if you test on the simulator with iphone 4 ?

Comment: You only have the option of a 3.5 inch simulator not a iphone 4 or iphone 4s but yes it does work perfectly fine on the 3.5inch simulator

Comment: Just for the sake of troubleshooting, try swapping that image out for a different one. Try to determine if there is some kind of difference in the image file itself. I'm not beyond the voodoo of renaming that file 'title.png' or swapping in another image just to see what happens in situations like this. I'd at least be exploring what is the difference between these 2 images and the others, whether it be the physical file format, filesize, naming convention, or even how they added - ie is this image added to the scene or another class node ?

Comment: Also try loading that same image as replacement for another image that is currently not blacking out... voodoo time  :)

Comment: I'll give all those things a go thanks for the reply :)

Comment: Definitely comment if you get it figured out.

Comment: Also, are you preloading those images ? That might be worth a try as well, if you are not. There are issues that occur with audio/fonts when you don't preload. Perhaps the increased file size is causing a similar issue that is device specific if you are not preloading. You can find reference here for how to preload - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Sprites/Sprites.html

Comment: Don't have an iPhone 4 to test on at the moment but when i get my hands on one somehow ill be sure to update whether it worked here :)

Comment: @prototypical Success! :) I shad a look at both the images that blacked out and found that they were the largest images in the app just resized through code to fit on the screen. It changed the images to much smaller images and but still compatible with retina display and it fixed the issue! :) must be that the iPhone 4 couldn't handle such a large image while the new generation iPhones could handle it...Thanks so much been a great help!

Comment: Great, glad you got it solved. What was the filesize of the old/new images ? Did you try the preloading ? I know you have it solved for your own personal use, but information like that would be helpful to others who might run into this.

Comment: The old file some of the first image was something ridiculous, 3268 × 1768, then resized to something 20 times smaller. I changed it to 1307 x 707 and therefore put a lot less stress on the phone. I did also preload the images which i don't think fixed to problem but is very good coding practice and made for quick load time. Thanks for you help

Comment: well.. there you go :) What was the filesize ? For the small area that image takes up on the screen, 3268x1768 seems to be rather large. Had you put the filesize and resolution in the question, i'm sure many would have questioned that immediately and saved a bunch of time.

Comment: yeah i hadn't actually realised it myself...just was a bit panicked why it wasn't working and wanted to get it fixed on the app store. Surprised apple didn't pick it up in their review...

Comment: I doubt they even check it on all devices.